# Gimp: opening clipboard as new image, with correct pixel size / dimensions?

Tags: resolution, clipboard, gimp, image-editing, image-processing

I often find myself having a picture in my clipboard, and then I want to quickly edit that in Gimp.

So I <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to Gimp (using the latest Gimp on macOS Catalina) and do <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> for New Image.

Problem: it now shows some default new image size, typically 1920 x 1200, whereas I'd rather have it use the clipboard content's resolution.
Right now I have to:

1. enlarge the canvas to something too large (I usually don't exactly know how large the clipboard image actually is)
2. paste clipboard as layer
3. turn that into a new layer (by default it's a floating selection, not yet a layer)
4. right click the layer in the layer list, and select Alpha to Selection
5. choose Image > Crop to Selection

Seems kinda inefficient. Would be great if Gimp could assume the dimensions of whatever image is in the clipboard (if any) as the default size. Actually Photoshop does this, very practical imho.

Is this possible in Gimp?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Edit>Paste as>New image` or `File>Create>From clipboard` will do what you are looking for. Same function under two different names, so same shortcut: Ctrl-Shift-V.

Note that if you paste as a layer, you can do `Image>Fit canvas to layers` to have Gimp shrink-wrap the pasted layer.